# How to retrieve checkboxlist values in the controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, checkboxlist

I am having a form in a view page that looks as below:

```
<form runat="server" id="dcrsubmit">
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>test1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>test2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>test3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>test4</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>test5</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>test6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

....other controls
</form>
```

Now when the form is posted, I am trying to retrieve the values submitted in the controller as below:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult testmethod(FormCollection formValues)
{
  string s = formvalues.get("CheckBoxList1");
   .
   .  /* other code */
   .
}
```

The string value shows null when I submit the form by checking some checkboxes. Is this the way to retrieve the values or am I doing something wrong? And I cannot use html control because all other controls on the form are server controls and I am not sure if I can only make this control a html control. And I am not sure how can I bind the values to it?

Comment: Servers controls are not working on asp.net MVC. To generate a checkbox use either <input type="checkbox" ...> or <%: Html.CheckBox(...) %>

Answer (score 2):

MVCContrib supply some excellent extensions to provide many controls and they also have a CheckBoxList.

To get started with MVCContrib, [read this](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&ProjectName=mvccontrib)

You'll need to use a strongly typed view and include this import statement in the view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Models.HomeModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcContrib.FluentHtml" %>
```

This example works. Here is the code on the view.

```
    <%= this.CheckBoxList("UserType").Options(Model.UserTypeOptions) %>
```

Here is the controller.

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Submit(HomeModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel.SelectedUserType == UserTypeEnum.Normal)
        {
            // do something
        }
        return View("Index", viewModel);
    }
```

Here is the model.

```
public enum UserTypeEnum
{
    Administrator = 0,
    SuperUser,
    Supervisor,
    Normal,
}
public class HomeModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> UserTypeOptions { get; set; }
    public string UserType { get; set; }

    public UserTypeEnum SelectedUserType
    {
        get
        {
            return (UserTypeEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof (UserTypeEnum), UserType);
        }
    }

    public HomeModel()
    {
        UserTypeOptions = new List<SelectListItem>
                       {
                           new SelectListItem{Text = "Administrator", Value = ((int)UserTypeEnum.Administrator).ToString()},
                           new SelectListItem{Text = "SuperUser", Value = ((int)UserTypeEnum.SuperUser).ToString()},
                           new SelectListItem{Text = "Supervisor", Value = ((int)UserTypeEnum.Supervisor).ToString()},
                           new SelectListItem{Text = "Normal", Value = ((int)UserTypeEnum.Normal).ToString()},
                       };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is how gather selected values from CheckBoxList that user selected and here is my solution for that:

1- Download Jquery.json.js and add it to your view as refrence:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
2- I've added a ".cssMyClass" to all checkboxlist items so I grab the values by their css class: 


 <script type="text/javascript" >
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#btnSubmit").click(sendValues);
         });

         function populateValues()
         {
             var data = new Array();
             $('.myCssClas').each(function () {
                 if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                     var x = $(this).attr("value");
                     data.push(x);
                 }
             }); 

             return data;
         }

         function sendValues() {
             var data = populateValues();
                   $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/Save")',
                       data: $.json.encode(data),
                       dataType: 'json',
                       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                       success: function () { alert("1"); }
                   });

           } 



     </script>
```

3- As you can see I've added all selected values to an Array and I've passed it to "Save" action of "Home" controller by ajax
4- in Controller you can receive the values by adding an array as argument:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(int[] val)
        {
```

I've searched too much but apparently this is the only solution. Please let me know if you find a better solution for it.