# Trying to save comma-separated list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

Trying to save selections from a CheckBoxList as a comma-separated list (`string`) in DB (one or more choices selected).  I am using a proxy in order to save as a `string` because otherwise I'd have to create separate tables in the DB for a relation - the work is not worth it for this simple scenario and I was hoping that I could just convert it to a `string` and avoid that.

The CheckBoxList uses an `enum` for it's choices:

```
public enum Selection 
{ 
    Selection1,
    Selection2,
    Selection3
}
```

Not to be convoluted, but I use `[Display(Name="Choice 1")]` and an extension class to display something friendly on the UI. Not sure if I can save that `string` instead of just the `enum`, although I think if I save as `enum` it's not a big deal for me to "display" the friendly string on UI on some confirmation page.

This is the "Record" class that saves a `string` in the DB:

```
public virtual string MyCheckBox { get; set; }
```

This is the "Proxy", which is some sample I found but not directly dealing with `enum`, and which uses `IEnumerable<string>` (or should it be `IEnumerable<Selection>`?):

```
public IEnumerable<string> MyCheckBox
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Record.MyCheckBox)) return new string[] { };
            return Record
                .MyCheckBox
                .Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(r => r.Trim())
                .Where(r => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r));
    }
    set
    { 
        Record.MyCheckBox = value == null ? null : String.Join(",", value); 
    }
}
```

To save in the DB, I am trying to do this in a create class:

```
proxy.MyCheckBox = record.MyCheckBox; //getting error here
```

but am getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert 'string' to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

I don't know, if it's possible or better, to use `Parse` or `ToString` from the API for enum values.

I know that doing something like this will store whatever I put in the `("")` into the DB, so it's just a matter of figuring out how to overcome the error (or, if there is an alternative):

```
proxy.MyCheckBox = new[] {"foo", "bar"};
```

I am not good with this stuff and have just been digging and digging to come up with a solution. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your code's getter splits on a '.' while the setter joins on ','. Is that correct?

Comment: sorry, thats a typo - fixing code

Comment: Ok, so your proxy's MyCheckBox is IEnumerable<string>, whereas Record.MyCheckBox is a string. These two are incompatible while assignment. I'm not sure I get the purpose of "proxy" here.

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan Because I can't save MyCheckBox in DB doing something like `IList<string>` or `IList<Selection>` because I would need to create separate associating tables for the relation. I was hoping I could convert it to a string and save it that way rather than type up a lot of code to create the relation

Comment: This answer illustrates how MVCContrib can help binding a Checkboxlist. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2734245/326543. Maybe you could build on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using a custom user type. The example below uses an `ISet<string>` on the class and stores the values as a delimited string.

```
[Serializable]
public class CommaDelimitedSet : IUserType
{
    const string delimiter = ",";

    #region IUserType Members

    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }
        var xSet = x as ISet<string>;
        var ySet = y as ISet<string>;
        if (xSet == null || ySet == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // compare set contents
        return xSet.Except(ySet).Count() == 0 && ySet.Except(xSet).Count() == 0;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var outValue = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]) as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(outValue))
        {
            return new HashSet<string>();
        }
        else
        {
            var splitArray = outValue.Split(new[] {Delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            return new HashSet<string>(splitArray);
        }
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        var inValue = value as ISet<string>;
        object setValue = inValue == null ? null : string.Join(Delimiter, inValue);
        NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, setValue, index);
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        // return new ISet so that Equals can work
        // see http://www.mail-archive.com/nhusers@googlegroups.com/msg11054.html
        var set = value as ISet<string>;
        if (set == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return new HashSet<string>(set);
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return DeepCopy(cached);
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return DeepCopy(value);
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return new[] {new SqlType(DbType.String)}; }
    }

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(ISet<string>); }
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Usage in mapping file:

```
Map(x => x.CheckboxValues.CustomType<CommaDelimitedSet>();
```